# ASP.NET Card view from Repeater with paging capabilities

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, pagination, repeater

I need to create a carview as gridview. Any suggestion?
I can use any free (must be stable) or open source tool.
My main concern is using micro soft **repeater with paging capabilities**
1. Is it the best practice?
2. What are the main point I must keep in mind for this?
3. I need to reuse this control in many pages as well many projects. So creating a web server control is right option?
**EDIT**
Is it possible to achieve cardview with micro soft gridview control?